# Translate paragraph to pig latin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I am trying to translate a page to pig latin using Javascript. I have the logic to translate but I am not able to fetch the paragraph. 
MY webpage has two paragraphs and a translate button. When the button is clicked, a new window should be opened with the same paragraphs in pig latin.
Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title> String Manipulation </title>
 <head> 
 <center><h1 style="color:Blue; font-family:verdana;"> BURJ KHALIFA</h1> <hr>
<img src ="burjkhalifa.jpeg" width = "650" height ="370"></center>
<script  type= "text/javascript">

    function getTranslate()
        {
        var text = document.getElementById("pagetitle").value;
        newWindow = window.open(text, "myWindow");
        var newWindowBody = newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        newWindowBody.setAttribute("onload", "window.opener.getParagraphs()");
        }

    function getParagraphs() {
        var pElement = newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        var str='';
        for( var counter =0; counter < pElement.length;counter++)
        {
            document.writeln(translate(pElement[counter].innerHTML));
            document.writeln("<p>&nbsp;</p>")

        }

}

    function translate(word)
    {  
      var array = word.split('');
      var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
      var newWord = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < vowels.length-1; i++) 
     {
        for(var y = 0; y < array.length-1; y++) 
        {
            if(array[y] == vowels[i])
            {
              for(var x = y; x < array.length; x++)
                {
                 newWord = newWord + array[x];
                }
                for(var n = 0; n < y; n++)
                { 
                     newWord = newWord + array[n];
                }
                newWord += "ay";
            }       
        }
    }
    }
    return newWord;
</script>
</head>

<body> 

<p style="font-family:courier; font-size:100%;">
The Burj Khalifa, known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, 
United Arab Emirates. It has a roof height of 828 m (2,717 ft), and with its antenna included, it stands 
 a total height of 829.8 m (2,722 ft), making it the tallest building and the tallest structure in the world. 
</p>

<p style="font-family:courier; font-size:100%;">
Construction of the Burj Khalifa began in 2004, with the exterior completed 5 years later in 2009. The primary 
structure is reinforced concrete. The building was opened in 2010 as part of a new development called Downtown Dubai. 
It is designed to be the centrepiece of large-scale, mixed-use development. The decision to build the building is 
reportedly based on the government's decision to diversify from an oil-based economy, and for Dubai to gain international 
recognition. The building was named in honour of the ruler of Abu Dhabi and president of the United Arab Emirates, Khalifa 
bin Zayed Al Nahyan; Abu Dhabi and the UAE government lent Dubai money to pay its debts. The building broke numerous height
records, including its designation as the tallest tower in the world. 
 </p>


<input  type="button" id = "submit" name="" value="Translate"  style="color: green; font-size:18pt"size ="10" onclick ="getTranslate()" />  

</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console? On a side note, you appear to be missing a closing body tag and using the `<center>` tag which doesn't exist.

Comment: I am not able to fetch the paragraphs. When I click the translate button, nothing happens.

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools (F12) and check out what it says in the console

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1.`return newWord` should be inside the `translate` function

2.`var text = document.getElementById("pagetitle").value;` returns null because there is no element with an id of "pagetitle"

3.right after your `<title>`, there is an extra opening `<head>` element

Try looking in the console on Firefox or Chrome to see if there are any errors.